# Problem using two event listeners where second event listener starts after the first event listener is started

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I am trying to use an event listener which works only after other event listener is initiated but it doesn't work when I do such as given in my code but the code works when I use a single event listener.

Code:

```
function changeColor(){
            let slab=document.querySelector('.container');
            slab.addEventListener('onclick',function activateOnMouseClick(){
                let slab=document.querySelectorAll('div .item');
                slab.forEach((slabs)=>
                    slabs.addEventListener('mouseover',function changeGridColor(){
                        slabs.setAttribute('style','background: blue; font-size:30px; text-align: center; border:0px solid white');
                }));
            });
        }
```

What this code should do is when I click on an item it should activate mouseover event listener which than changes color of that item.

live(using only mouseover):[working][1]

In live as you hover mouse in the rectangle the tiles change their color but what I want is them to change color only when I first use mouseclick to activate this color change on mouseover.
[1]: https://utsavj.github.io/etch-a-sketch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
slab.addEventListener('onclick',function activateOnMouseClick(){
```

The correct syntax is `click`

```
slab.addEventListener('click', function activateOnMouseClick() {
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Etch-a-sketch</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: grid;
            height: 400px;
            width: 400px;
            grid-gap: 1px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>Etch-a-sketch</h1>
    <button id="reset" onclick="resetColor()">Reset</button><br>
    <button onclick="size()">Set Size</button><br>

    <div class="container">
    </div>
    <script>
        function numberOfGrids() {
            let container = document.querySelector('.container');
            for (i = 1; i <= (16 * 16); i++) {
                let item = document.createElement('div')
                item.classList.add('item');
                item.setAttribute('style', 'font-size: 30px; text-align: center; border: 0px solid white');
                container.appendChild(item);
            }
        }

        function changeColor() {
            let slab = document.querySelectorAll('div .item');
            slab.forEach((slabs) =>
                slabs.addEventListener('mouseover', function changecolor() {
                    slabs.setAttribute('style', 'background: blue; border: 0px solid white');
                }));
        }

        function changeColor() {
            let slab = document.querySelector('.container');
            slab.addEventListener('click', function activateOnMouseClick() {
                let slab = document.querySelectorAll('div .item');
                slab.forEach((slabs) =>
                    slabs.addEventListener('mouseover', function changeGridColor() {
                        slabs.setAttribute('style', 'background: blue; font-size:30px; text-align: center; border:0px solid white');
                    }));
            });
        }

        function resetColor() {
            let item = document.querySelectorAll('div .item');
            item.forEach((items) =>
                items.setAttribute('style', 'background:white; border: 0px solid white'));

        }

        function size() {
            let size = prompt("Enter the size", "");
            let container = document.querySelector('.container');
            while (container.firstChild) {
                container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
            }
            container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, auto)`;
            container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size}, auto)`;

            for (i = 1; i <= (size * size); i++) {
                let item = document.createElement('div');
                item.classList.add('item');
                item.setAttribute('style', 'font-size: 30px; text-align: center; border: 0px solid white');
                container.appendChild(item);

            }
            changeColor();
        }

        size(16);
        //numberOfGrids();
        changeColor();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```